# Better way for al lot of if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a function to change the background color depending on the value of a slider

There are 35 different colors and I now use this code for it (of course it is longer)

```
if (value < 25) {
    color = '#FFFFFF';
} else if (value > 25 && value < 50) {
    color = '#F8F8F8';
} else if (value > 50 && value < 75) {
    color = '#F0F0F0 ';
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this up?

Comment: You don't really have to retest the negative in the else statement...

Comment: What happens if value == 25?

Comment: Value is never 25 it goes in steps of 25 and starts with 5
But I should not retest the negative, that makes it easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're incrementing by 25, then make an Array of colors:

```
var colors = ['#FFFFFF', '#F8F8F8', '#F0F0F0 ', ... ]
```

And then do a little math to see which index to use.

```
color = colors[(value - (value % 25)) / 25];
```

---

Or if you prefer:

```
color = colors[Math.floor(value / 25)];
```

Comment: It would be cheaper computationally to use something like `colors[(value / 25) | 0]` to do integer division, rather than using the mod operator (or even calling `Math.floor`).

Comment: @TedHopp: Any performance gain multiplied by the total number of times this code will ever run will likely be less than the time it took you to type that comment. ;-)

Comment: the first way is terrible, you use two divisions and subtraction just to get an index ;-(

Comment: @elmes: And you're using a function... just to get an index. To say it's "terrible" is nonsense.

Comment: arguably the second solution is cleaner, or at least more intuitive

Comment: @elmes: Fine, the absolute statement is now a subjective statement of personal preference. These are two very different comments.

Comment: I really like this solution, only problem is that I don't know where I start. Generally it's at 430 but it can vary depending on the size of the browser

To make it a little bit more clear, I use jquery ui draggable on the logo of my site, and the logo starts in the middle of the page.

Comment: @eric22269: You'd just subtract the variable starting point from the value before doing the math.

Comment: @thesystem - In this case perhaps the gain is trivial, but the technique of converting a result to an int by using a bitwise operator is useful more generally. In some situations (probably not this one, I grant you) it can make a huge difference in performance. There's no reason to pooh-pooh it.

Comment: @TedHopp: I don't doubt that in some cases, in some languages, that can be the case. But in this scenario, clearly any difference either way will be entirely irrelevant. But just so that we don't make too many assumptions about performance, I threw together [a jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-vs-math-operation). In Firefox, a minimal edge was given to the bitwise operation, but in Chromium, a greater edge was given to the math operation.

Comment: @thesystem - Those results are a bit surprising. I wonder what's going on. Also, I wonder if the "math" version is guaranteed to give an integer value, or if there are occasional rounding errors that end up with the result off by one.

Comment: @thesystem - I added a Math.floor snippet to make [rev 2 of the test](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-vs-math-operation/2).

Comment: @TedHopp: I'll grant that the Firefox version may have optimized away the entire operation, since historically Chrome has had better JS performance. But I'm not sure how there could be a rounding error. The modulus will return an integer, which when subtracted will provide a number perfectly divisible by `25`, so I wouldn't think floating point issues would come into play. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TedHopp: Here's your test [updated](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-vs-math-operation/3) to bring the `Math.random()` directly into each test. That addition into the timed region seems to have zero impact on the operations per second in Firefox, so I do think that Firefox is optimizing away the entire operation. EDIT: wait... there seems to be a small impact, so now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a two line statement, without arrays, by doing something similar to this:

```
var rgbvalue = 255-Math.floor(value/25);
var color = 'rgb('+rgbvalue+','+rgbvalue+','+rgbvalue+');';
```

Of course you would have to limit the value, so that the rgbvalue doesn't get smaller than 0, but I guess you can easily do that, if you know the possible values.
And if you want it to get dark faster, you can multiply the result of the Math.floor operation, like this:

```
var rgbvalue = 255-(Math.floor(value/25)*5);
```

And you have the advantage that you don't have to write a huge array of shades of gray.

Answer (score 1):

More bullet-proof version (not fully -proof though)

```
var colors = ['#FFFFFF','#F8F8F8','#F0F0F0'];

/* this is not that necessary */
var value = input_value || default_input_value;

var color = colors[ Math.floor(value/25) ];
```

Comment: Instead of having a default input value, and a default index, why not simplify and just have a default color? `var color = colors[Math.floor(value / 25)] || default_color;`

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = {'#FFFFFF','#F8F8F8','#F0F0F0 '}
color=colors[(int)value/25];
```

You may need to adjust this depending on the range of `value`.

Comment: sorry... thought this was java, the same concept applies though

Comment: I like this idea, I'm gone try to create an array

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `&&` and cascade instead

```
if(values > 75){
  //anything above 75 falls here
} 
else if(value > 50){
  //anything <= 75 but > 50 falls here
} 
else if(values > 25){
  //anything <= 50 but > 25 falls here
} 
else {
  //anything <= 25 falls here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of objects that describe the color and the min and max of the range and then use a function to iterate through the array to find the color between the range.

```
function getColor(value) {

    var colorRanges = [
        { color : '#FFFFFF', min : 0, max : 25 },
        { color : '#F8F8F8', min : 25, max : 50 },
        { color : '#F0F0F0', min : 50, max : 75 }
    ],
    length = colorRanges.length;

    while(length--) {
        var colorRange = colorRanges[length];
        if (value >= colorRange.min && value < colorRange.max) {
            return colorRange.color;
        }
    }

    // default color
    return colorRanges[0].color;
}
```

With a little additional effort, you could expose a way to add new colors and ranges, have a default for the range interval, etc. If your colors and range interval are fixed however, this is probably overkill.